# React Markdown links dont open in a new tab despite using target="_blank"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, react-markdown

small component looks like so:

```
// @flow
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import type { Node } from "react";

function LinkRenderer(props: any) {
  return (
    <a href={props.href} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
      {props.children}
    </a>
  );
}

type Props = {
  children: Node,
};

const MarkdownRenderer = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return (
    <ReactMarkdown components={{ link: LinkRenderer }}>
      {children}
    </ReactMarkdown>
  );
};
```

Can anyone suggest why my links aren't opening in a new tab when using this component?

Implementing the component like so in other components:

```
<MarkdownRenderer>{value}</MarkdownRenderer>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to update the prop from the 'link' to 'a' to achieve that.

```
  <ReactMarkdown components={{ a: LinkRenderer}}>
      {children}
  </ReactMarkdown>
```

Please find the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-field-r8d3c?file=/src/App.js) link

Also if you are not doing too much customization and added the custom renderer just for opening a link in a new tab. You can make use of 'linkTarget' prop and set it to '_blank'

Answer (score 6):

You can use `linkTarget` now to make your link open in a new tab:

```
<ReactMarkdown linkTarget="_blank" children={...} />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Be aware that the maintainers are about to drop linkTarget attribute in https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown/pull/762. Using the component answer is probably the best for future use.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of `react-markdown`, use of `linkTarget="_blank"` has being remove. Instead of that we have to use [rehype-external-links](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rehype-external-links)

```
<ReactMarkdown  rehypePlugins={[[rehypeExternalLinks, {target: '_blank'}]]}
                                                         children={message.text}/>
```