# react-markdown not support target blank

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

I use react-markdown and I wont use target in "" tag and I use <ReactMarkdown to convert markdown to HTML
I can't use HTML syntax and I can't add target_black to "" tag

```
[Link](https://example.org/ target="_blank")  
"<a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">demo</a>  "
```

and I got the output just like this
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9gJ4.png)

Why react-markdown dosn't support HTML syntax and target new window redirection and how can I add this solution

Comment: Possible copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69119798/react-markdown-links-dont-open-in-a-new-tab-despite-using-target-blank

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.